# Accessing JSON.stringify variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have trouble in accessing the JSON string being sent from my client side Javascript code to my PHP code. This is what I have done until now.

```
var formatted;
fr.onload = function(e) {
var result = JSON.parse(e.target.result);
formatted = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);
console.log(formatted);

//send formatted as post to write2share.php and write that in a file in    share folder

xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "write2share.php";
var nametime = gettime();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(json.content);
}
}
var data = JSON.stringify({"content":formatted, "name": nametime});
xhr.send(data);
//GenerateShare(nametime);

}
```

Here formatted is a JSON string and nametime is an integer

The below is my php script

```
$decoded = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);

$error = json_last_error();
var_dump($decoded);
echo $error;
```

The output of my $error is 0 and var_dump of $decoded is Null. Why?

Help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: "The output of my $error is 0 and var_dump of $decoded is Null." — How are you inspecting this output?

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes I am running this on a Webserver (VM). And I did take a look at the requests and response. The JSON seems to be a valid file, I tested it out on jsonlint as well. I am wondering if this has anything to do with the encoding ? the variable formatted has special characters in it.

Comment: @Quentin I just echoed it and this is what it shows on the page write2share.php

Comment: @Manikv — It's the response to an Ajax request. If you "just echo it" then you wouldn't see anything (because it isn't JSON so `var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);` would fail)

Comment: @Quentin I see what you are getting at. So how can I inspect if the JSON is  received in the php file? the response status shows 200 ok so i am assuming that the content type and headers are ok.

Comment: Examining it in the Network tab of your browser's developer tools would be a good start.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I did that and I seem to have successfully sent the JSON from the source file to the destination. But I am not able to access the JSON on the destination.

Comment: Have You checked network tab in Chrome Inspector?

Comment: according restrictions in http://us.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php  please check `allow_url_include` setting in php

Comment: also do following: `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input")); die;` and see if anything has been sent to Your php code.

Comment: @num8er I edited the php.ini to allow url include and restarted it. The var_dump results in string(0) "".

Comment: Can You console.log data variable before You send it?